# Identifying Two-worded cities ('New York') in a text

Tags: python, nltk

For this Code, I am provided a text file that contain several cities. I am suppose to identify the cities mentioned and print their state and country.

**Requirements:**
If a mentioned city is in two or more countries, I ask the user to mention which city they are talking about. In addition if there is a slight typo, I ask the user if they meant a certain city instead. For example if they type 'Dalls' instead of 'Dallas' I need to provide the user options such as 'Do you mean Dallas instead of Dalls'.

**Problem:**
So far I have been successful in meeting these conditions but when it comes to identifying two worded cities such as 'New York' or 'San Francisco' My program is unable to. This is because I am reading through the text word by wordIf you have any recommendations on how to better read the text please let me know.

**P.S.**(I know that the code can be more simplified with more advanced python methods but my knowledge in Python has not reached that level yet. However please do let me know how else I can simplify my program as I feel it is unnecessary lengthly right now. Thanks!)

**File Explanations:**
I am using a text called 'world-cities.csv', 'TEXT.txt' and 'usa.txt'. 'world-cities.csv' is a file that contains a lot of cities in the world. 'TEXT.txt' is a file that contains the sentences that I will be analyzing for cities. 'usa.txt' contains common words in the english language. I used it to compare to 'TEXT.txt' to remove common words. I had a problem with words such as 'and' showing up as typos. So this was a bootleg method to get rid of them.

**TextFile:** 
Today I went to Hyderabad, then I traveled to Chennai and New York in United States. Now I am traveling to Tokyo and back Rochester to tomorrow. Dalls and sdney are my next destinations.

I have used Geotext, which works but the problem occurs when reading cities such as 'New York'. My part of the program without geotext read in 'York' and when I add Geotext it reads 'New York'. As a result my cities list has 'York' and 'New York'. I was told I can use the NLTK package but Im still searching for an effective way to do it.

enter code here

```
import pandas as pd
import re


#imported dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('world-cities.csv')

#assigned certain parts of data set to variable
data = dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
city = dataset.iloc[:,0]
state = dataset.iloc[:,2]
country = dataset.iloc[:,1]


#opened and imported textfile
txtfile = open('TEXT.txt','r')
txtfile = txtfile.read()
words = open('usa.txt','r')
words = words.read()


#getting rid of punctation
altered = re.sub("[.,:]",'',txtfile)
templist = [] #holds the cities(state and country) info of the places 
final = [] #final array
all_cities = [] #used to check for repeating cities
repeat = {} #contains only city names
repeatinfo = [] #contain all infor about repeating cities
stupid = 0
close = 0
typo = []
typodict = {}
typecount = 0
finaltypo = []

#finding out where the talked about cities are 
for x in altered.split():
    count = 0
    zcount = 0
    for y in city:
        if x == y:
            zcount +=1
            templist.append([city[count], state[count], country[count]])
            all_cities.append(city[count])
        count+=1
     if zcount > 1:
        repeat[x] = zcount

#put in all assumed Typos
for x in altered.split():
    if x not in all_cities:
        x = x.lower()
        if x not in words:
            typo.append(x)


#narrow down options of typos
many = 0
for a in typo:
    for b in city:
        b = b.lower()
        if len(a) >= (len(b)-1) and len(a) <= (len(b)+1):
            if a[0] == b[0] or a[-1::] == b[-1::]:
                if a[0:3] == b[0:3] or a[-3::] == b[-3::]:
                    #print(f'{a} vs {b}')
                    many = 0
                    for x in a:
                        if x in b:
                            many+=1
                        if many >= (len(b)-1) and many <= (len(b)+1):
                            typodict[b] = a

#let user choose if it is a typo or not
print('TYPO Checking')
for a in typo:
    p =0
    q = 0
    while(p < len(typo) and q == 0):
        for x,y in typodict.items():
            go2 = True
            while(go2 and q==0):
                if y == a:
                    user2 = input(f" Did you mean to type '{x}' instead of 
'{y}'? Enter 'y' or 'n': ")
                    user2 = user2.lower()
                    if user2 == 'y':
                        go2 = False
                        finaltypo.append(x)
                        p+=1
                        q+=1
                    elif user2 == 'n':
                        go2 = False
                    else: 
                        print('You have entered a invalid value')
                else:
                    go2 = False



#adding typoed cities into list
for x in finaltypo:
    x = x.capitalize()
    count = 0
    zcount = 0
    for y in city:
        if x == y:
            zcount +=1
            templist.append([city[count], state[count], country[count]])
            all_cities.append(city[count])
        count+=1
    if zcount > 1:
        repeat[x] = zcount

#finding out what cities repeat and adding all their information to repeat 
info
for x in repeat:
    rcount = 0
    for y in city:
        if x == y: 
            repeatinfo.append([city[rcount], state[rcount], 
country[rcount]])
        rcount +=1

#determining which country they mean when they mentioned repeating cities
print('Which City?')
for x,y in repeat.items():
    i = 0
    e = 0
    while(i < y and e == 0):
        go = True
        for c in repeatinfo: 
            go = True
            while(go and e == 0):
                if x == c[0]:
                    user = input(f'Do you mean {x} in {c[1]},{c[2]} enter y 
or n: ')
                    user = user.lower()
                    i +=1
                    if user == 'y':
                        final.append(f' {x} in {c[1]}, {c[2]}')
                        go = False
                        i +=1
                        e +=1
                    elif user == 'n':
                        go = False
                        i+=1
                    else:
                        print('You have entered a invalid input')
                else: 
                    go = False


#removing repeating cities from templist
for y in list(templist):
    if y[0] in list(repeat):
        templist.remove(y)

#adding remaining elements of templist to final list
for y in list(templist):
    final.append(f' {y[0]} in {y[1]}, {y[2]}')

#printing final output
print('\n You have entered the following cities:')               
for x in final:
    print(x)
```

The output here was for a different text file (one that didn't contain two-worded cities):

```
enter code here

 You have entered the following cities:
 Hyderabad in Telangana, India
 Rochester in New York, United States
 Sydney in Nova Scotia, Canada
 Chennai in Tamil Nadu, India
 Tokyo in Tokyo, Japan
 Dallas in Texas, United States
```

Comment: Use [spacy](https://spacy.io/)

Comment: Hi @Susanth Kakarla if any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that 'New York' id lidted in your `city` list.

I think yuou can do the searching this way:

```
#finding out where the talked about cities are
for count,y in enumerate(city):
    if y in altered:
        zcount +=1
        templist.append([city[count], state[count], country[count]])
        all_cities.append(city[count])
```

I hope this helps to give you the basic idea. If you need more help let me know.